# Save Java frame as a Microsoft Word or PDF document?

Tags: java, ms-word, save

I am working on a billing program - right now when you click the appropriate button it generates a frame that shows the various charges etc, basically an invoice.  Is there a way to give the user an option of saving that frame as a document, either [Microsoft Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word), [Microsoft Works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Works) or [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format)?

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to save the frame as an image, you can do that by using the following syntax to convert it to an image.

```
BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage(size.width,size.height,
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g2 = myImage.createGraphics();

myComponent.paint(g2);
```

you can then save this image and pass it into a jasper report.  From the JasperPrint object you can then save in a few different formats, including pdf.  A better but similar approach would be to pass the Graphics context into JasperReports(there is a renderer to do this in jasper, and the quality is much better).

Answer (score 2):

1. Paint `JFrame` in a `BufferedImage`. `paint()` method of `JFrame`
2. Save the image as jpg or png or whatever image format
3. Take some pdf library and create a blank pdf (e.g. iText)
4. Insert the image into the PDF document
5. Save it - done

Answer (score 2):

Instead of generating a word document, I'd rather use a Java library like [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) to produce a PDF document (more portable) or, even better, the [JasperReport](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports) report library that can output reports in a wide range of formats (PDF, XML, HTML, CSV, XLS, RTF, TXT) as suggested by [bigbrother82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3340/bigbrother82) in a comment. This looks cleaner to me than using an image, especially for printing (not even mentioning that your invoice may be a multi-page document).

Comment: I would also consider just using JasperReports (which uses itext to create pdfs) since you can write the report once and export it n rtf, word, pdf, or even html. So the user can choose. and it takes very little extra effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I'd likely look at this from a slightly different direction and instead of asking how to splat the GUI form as-is into a PDF or word document I'd ask how to get that content into a Word/PDF document.

The answer to that question is [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/). Generate a [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) file and ask FOP to convert it into a RTF document (with a .DOC extension) or a PDF.

Normally one does this by generating an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file containing the data you need printed. Then use an [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) to convert that XML to XSL-FO. I however found it easier to generate a XSL-FO file directly using a templating language (such as [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the online demo for [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com/demo) as an example which gives the user the options for requesting the document up front.  That demo does a download, but it could direct the document into a frame instead and leave it to the browser to display.  This style of working (as metioned by others) is looking at the problem from a different angle and deciding up front what format, rather than after the fact and then trying to save the frame contents.